# How can you conditionally select a Dictionary from an MVVM ViewModel using knockout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, knockout.js

I've got a selection of different Dictionaries in an MVC viewmodel that are to be used a the values for various drop down lists. I want to conditionally select which dictionary to use from my viewmodel using knockout.

So at the moment I have something like this in my viewmodel:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> MyOptions { get; set; }

public Dictionary<string, int> MyOptions2 { get; set; }
```

In my view I'm using an EditorFor like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyValue, "MyDropDown", new
{
    Options: Model.MyOptions
})
```

Within my MyDropDown partial view I'm doing:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model, ((Dictionary<int, string>)ViewData["Options"]).ToSelectList(Model.Value), attributes)
```

As you can see I'm basically trying to use ViewData["Options"] to populate my drop down list. Options is set as part of my EditorFor. How can I conditionally set Options in my EditorFor based on changes client-side? I've tried doing this:

```
<!-- ko if: isPackageA() -->
    @{
        myOptions = Model.MyOptions;
    }
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: isPackageB() -->
    @{
        myOptions = Model.MyOptions2;
    }
<!-- /ko -->
```

'myOptions' is simply a previously created variable of Dictionary. I then pass myOptions into the Options for the EditorFor. Unfortunately this is always ending up with MyOptions2 being set. Is this the correct way to be doing it?

Comment: Given the `ko` bit is running client-side, and thus the server ignores it, the real code you are running server side is `@{
        myOptions = Model.MyOptions;
    } @{
        myOptions = Model.MyOptions2;
    }` What do you think that would do?

Comment: @mjwills - ok, so I can't run c# code wrapped in ko to do it. Any ideas how I can?

Comment: Have two different variables. In ko decide whether to bind to one, or the other.

Comment: In addition to what @mjwills mentioned, the containerless control flow syntax (`ko if: isPackageA()`) is used for **conditionally displaying HTML**. Not assign variables in your javascript code.

Comment: What about having 2 select elements rendered by C# and then one of them would be dynamically hidden by ko? Or passing 2 sets of options in ko VM with switching between them completely in js?